# How to know if all javascript object values are true?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, I need to know if all object items are set to true.

If I have the following object:

```
var myObj = {title:true, name:true, email:false};
```

I could write something like this :

```
 if(myObj.title && myObj.name && myObj.email){
 /*Some code */
};
```

But I am looking for the simplest way to write it. eg :

```
if(myObj all is true){
/*Some code */
};
```

I might have another object with 10-20 items inside it, and will need to know if all are true.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

How about something like:

```js
    function allTrue(obj)
    {
      for(var o in obj)
          if(!obj[o]) return false;
        
      return true;
    }
    
    var myObj1 = {title:true, name:true, email:false};
    var myObj2 = {title:true, name:true, email:true};

    document.write('<br />myObj1 all true: ' + allTrue(myObj1));
    document.write('<br />myObj2 all true: ' + allTrue(myObj2));
```

**A few disclaimers:** This will return `true` if all values are *true-ish*, not necessarily exactly equal to the Boolean value of True.  Also, it will scan *all* properties of the passed in object, including its prototype.  This may or may not be what you need, however it should work fine on a simple object literal like the one you provided.

Comment: You have also include check for `hasOwnProperty` otherwise object prototypes may interfere

Comment: Yeah I thought about including that but figured it would complicate the example too much.  So I pointed that out in my disclaimer.

Comment: Nice, but what if one of the property value is empty array [] and some other is null?

Answer (score 104):

With ES2017 [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) life's even simpler.

```
Object.values(yourTestObject).every(item => item)
```

Even shorter version with *[Boolean()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean)* function [thanks to [xab]](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7626876/xab)

```
Object.values(yourTestObject).every(Boolean)
```

Or with stricter *true* checks

```
Object.values(yourTestObject)
    .every(item => item === true)
```

Comment: To further simplify truthy values check: `Object.values(yourTestObject).every(Boolean)`

Comment: It would be good to include a link to documentation for that particular usage of Boolean. Essentially it is passing the Boolean() object wrapper as a function into the every() function. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean

Comment: That is the better answer imho. I will check but if you can answer it there, by chance: does it also work for nested values?

Comment: @Billybobbonnet For that you just have to modify the function expression you pass inside `every` method. For eg: `Object.values(target).every(item => item.deeply.nested.property === SOME_VALUE)`

Answer (score 63):

In modern browsers:

```
var allTrue = Object.keys(myObj).every(function(k){ return myObj[k] });
```

If you *really* want to check for `true` rather than just a truthy value:

```
var allTrue = Object.keys(myObj).every(function(k){ return myObj[k] === true });
```

Comment: or better yet, make it re-usable: Object.keys(myObj).every(function(k){ return this[k] }, myObj);

Comment: `myObj.every` won't work because `.every` is only for arrays

Answer (score 2):

Quickest way is a loop

```
for(var index in myObj){
  if(!myObj[index]){ //check if it is truly false
    var fail = true
  }
}
if(fail){
  //test failed
}
```

This will loop all values in the array then check if the value is false and if it is then it will set the fail variable, witch will tell you that the test failed.

Comment: There's probably no reason to continue the loop once you found a value that fails.

Comment: Yep... You can either use `break` to get out of the loop or simply return false if this snippet is part of a function (which it probably should be).

Comment: Very true, overlooked that aspect. I guess the application of this is expecting not a lot of actual values in the object, in witch case this would not cause much harm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `every` from lodash

```js
const obj1 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: true };
const obj2 = { a: true, b: true, c: true }; 

_.every(obj1, true);  // false
_.every(obj2, true);  // true
```

Comment: Both of these will return false