# If all value is false in object then object value should be False in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am getting one JSON data object. In the object multiple "key" "values". So I am trying to set "false" in one another variable, If even one key value is false.

I am sharing JSON data.

```
var objectVal= resp;
console.log("json data values", objectVal);
```

Below is the JSON DATA in console, Whole JSON data is dynamic.
Result on running first time

```
{"User_Name":{"color":true,"Edition":true,"Deletion":false}}  //result should true
```

Result on running second time

```
{"User_role":{"color":false,"Edition":true,"Deletion":true}}  //result should true
```

Result on running third time

```
{"User_role":{"color":false,"Edition":false,"Deletion":false}}  //result should false
```

I have seen one link, But in this link playing with varibale ..[How to know if all javascript object values are true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117712/how-to-know-if-all-javascript-object-values-are-true)

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, as an [edit] to your question, and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: It's really unclear of what you want in your current question that isn't answered with the link to the other question you've provided

Comment: As you said `set "false" If even one key value is false` but in first run you writed `true`!?

Comment: @Mohammad Yes, set false in one another variable.

Comment: How does the question you linked not help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function which will take the object as the parameter. Inside the function you can filter out the `true` values with `filter()`. You can then check the length to return `true` or `false` from the function.

Try the following way:

```js
var obj1 = {"User_Name":{"color":true,"Edition":true,"Deletion":false}}
var obj2 = {"User_role":{"color":false,"Edition":true,"Deletion":true}}
var obj3 = {"User_role":{"color":false,"Edition":false,"Deletion":false}}  

function getStatus(obj){
  obj = obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]];
  var s = Object.values(obj).filter(o => o);
  if(s.length) return true;
  else return false;
}
console.log(getStatus(obj1)); // true
console.log(getStatus(obj2)); // true
console.log(getStatus(obj3)); // false
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I don't want to hard code "User_Name", "User_role" on calling time. Because every time it is changing. It should console.log(getStatus(obj));

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. Please upvote my question. Because some guys downvoted two times.

Comment: Hi Mamun, Hope you are good.plz help me, If We will above object in the Array like.........[{"_id":"new-work","User-Name":{"color":false,"Edition":true,"Deletion":false}},  {{"_id":"old_work","User_Name":{"color":true,"Edition":true,"Deletion":false}}, {"_id":"medium-work"User_Name":{"color":true,"Edition":true,"Deletion":false}} ] . All color value is false then object should return single value as a false.

Comment: @VSH, arrays and objects manipulation are completely different. As it is not good practice to update question and answer with structure, you can better ask a new question......thanks.

Comment: plz check this link. Please upvot first otherwise sombody devote...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52496729/how-to-set-true-and-false-based-particular-key-in-object-array

Answer (score 0):

You can have a recursive function that will check all objects/values in the main object and return `false` if anything is indeed false.

```
function allTrue(ob) {
    let r = true;
    for (let v of Object.values(ob)) {
        r &= (typeof v === 'object') ? allTrue(v) : v;
    }
    return !!r; // return true/false instead of 1/0
}

let o1 = { a:true, b:true, c:true } // allTrue(o1) > true
let o2 = { a:true, b:true, c:false } // allTrue(o2) > false
let o3 = { a:{ a1:true, a2:true }, b:true} // allTrue(o3) > true
let o4 = { a:false, b:{ b1:false, b2:true }} // allTrue(o4) > false

console.log('o1', allTrue(o1), 'o2', allTrue(o2), 'o3', allTrue(o3), 'o4', allTrue(o4))
```