# How to set True and False based particular key in object Array?

Tags: javascript, json

I am calling one API and getting the response (Below is the response)
I am getting `JOHN_FARY` from the session and I want to check only `JOHN_FARY` key values, Even View is false for all `_id` then it should return a `false` value.

Suppose, If I will get JACKY_MANY then check should be same.

```
[
  {
    "_id": "app-first",
    "project": "Backend",
    "accessForPortal": "userPortal",
    "visible": true,
    "JOHN_FARY": {
      "View": true,
      "Down": true,
      "Up": true,
      "Left": true
    },
    "JACKY_MANY": {
      "View": true,
      "Down": true,
      "Up": true,
      "Left": true
    },
    "JACK_MAN": {
      "View": true,
      "Down": true,
      "Up": true,
      "Left": true
    },
    "GROUND_POL": {
      "View": true,
      "Down": true,
      "Up": true,
      "Left": true
    },
    "_etag": {
      "$oid": "5b7c07364b402e87085d9d7f"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "app-rule-second",
    "project": "Backend",
    "accessForPortal": "userPortal",
    "JOHN_FARY": {
      "View": true,
      "Enable": true,
      "Edit": true,
      "Delete": true
    },
    "JACKY_MANY": {
      "View": true,
      "Enable": true,
      "Edit": true,
      "Delete": true
    },
    "JACK_MAN": {
      "View": true,
      "Enable": true,
      "Edit": true,
      "Delete": true
    },
    "GROUND_POL": {
      "View": true,
      "Enable": true,
      "Edit": true,
      "Delete": true
    },
    "_etag": {
      "$oid": "5b7c07364b402e87085d9d7f"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "app-thirs-rules",
    "project": "Backend",
    "visible": true,
    "accessForPortal": "userPortal",
    "JOHN_FARY": {
      "View": true,
      "Enable": true,
      "Edit": true,
      "Delete": true
    },
    "JACKY_MANY": {
      "View": true,
      "Enable": true,
      "Edit": true,
      "Delete": true
    },
    "JACK_MAN": {
      "View": true,
      "Enable": true,
      "Edit": true,
      "Delete": true
    },
    "GROUND_POL": {
      "View": true,
      "Enable": true,
      "Edit": true,
      "Delete": true
    },
    "_etag": {
      "$oid": "5b7c07364b402e87085d9d7f"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: so if view is false for all id-s than it should return false, otherwise true?

Comment: @Deda Yes Bro, It should be false. According to object name, If I will get from session JOHN_FARY, then in this only.

Comment: The question is quite unclear, please try to reframe the question possibly with a small and understandable example. Also, have you tried doing it yourself? Please upload that version.

Comment: It would be better to write generic Json, and question as well. Here its confusing.

Comment: Do you just want to check if all `View` fields of a specific resource (JOHN_FARY/JACKY_MANY ) are false?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways, but this one should be simplest.

```
function getView(name){
     return response.some(e=>e[name].View === true)
}

getView('JOHN_FARY') // true
```

Comment: could you upvote, Somebody downvote the question. Thanks for the answer.