# Angular 7 - collection of objects if any item has a property true

Tags: angular, angular7

How can I run an `*ngIf` on a collection if there is any item in collection that has a property true?

```
var data ={
  Collection: [
     {Flag : true },
     {Flag : true },
     {Flag : true },
     {Flag : false }
  ]
}
```

how can I do `*ngIf="data.Collection.ANY(Flag == true)"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117712/how-to-know-if-all-javascript-object-values-are-true

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know if all javascript object values are true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117712/how-to-know-if-all-javascript-object-values-are-true)

Answer (score 2):

You can conveniently use js [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) here as follows -

`<div *ngIf="data.Collection.some(x=>x.Flag)"></div>`

Here's a working example for **`some()`** -

```js
var data ={
  Collection: [
     {Flag : true },
     {Flag : true },
     {Flag : true },
     {Flag : false }
  ]
}

// you may use it this way too - x => x.Flag == true
console.log(data.Collection.some(x => x.Flag));
```

Comment: I get this error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column

Comment: If you get that error, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43118484/1331040) might help you along with this answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngIf="data.Collection.filter(x=>x.Flag).length"></div>
```

if you want to handle undefined also

```
 <div *ngIf="data.Collection&&data.Collection.filter(x=>x.Flag).length"></div>
```

Comment: I get this error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
*ngIf="data.Collection.reduce((a, b) => a || b.Flag, true)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a function as bellow in your component

```
public hasFlag(): boolean {
  return this.data.collection && this.data.collection.some(item => item. Flag);
}
```

Now call to that function

*ngIf="hasFlag()"

Hope you won't get the binding error